# Accessing a web service in a Flash CS3 AS3 project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, web-services

Since CS3 doesn't have a web service component, as previous versions had, is there a good, feature-complete, AS3-only (no Flex dependencies) library for accessing web services with AS3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out 
http://alducente.wordpress.com/2007/10/27/web-service-in-as3-release-10/

Comment: More recent version (1.1) fixes a problem we had with XFire-generated services: http://labs.alducente.com/?page_id=11

Answer (score 0):

What type of service are you trying to consume? URLLoader can handle soap requests (`urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml"));`) and NetConnection can handle most other stuff (AMF/Remoting).